# Unable to see trace id in respone headers, when open-telemetry java agent being used

Tags: spring-boot, open-telemetry

As part of my springboot application , i am using open-telemetry  java agent.
Traces are coming fine in jaeger. But unable to find trace id in response for my debugging activity.

i want to use trace id from response to search in jaeger.

Thanks
Sai

Answer (score 1):

By default the javaagent does not return the trace information in the HTTP response. The reason for that is that there is no standard HTTP header that can be used to do that.

However, the mechanism that allows appending headers to HTTP responses is already in place, and you can build a custom javaagent [extension](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/extensions/) that implements the [`HttpServerResponseCustomizer`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/javaagent-extension-api/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/javaagent/bootstrap/http/HttpServerResponseCustomizer.java) SPI and adds headers in whatever format you prefer. ([here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/testing/agent-exporter/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/javaagent/testing/http/TestAgentHttpResponseCustomizer.java)'s an example implementation)